# Find the edges emanating from a given vertex in a polyhedron defined by $P=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax=b, x\geq0 \}$

Tags: geometry, convex-optimization

> Suppose my polyhedron $P$ is defined as $P=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax=b, x\geq0 \}$. I have $x_0$, which is a vertex of $P$. How to find the edges emanating from $x_0$?

In other words, I want to find the set $D={ d_1, \cdots, d_n}$ such that $x_0+\lambda d_i$ is a vertex for some $\lambda>0$.

Is there a way of getting $D$ using $A$, $b$ and $x_0$? This is needed to code up a cutting plane algorithm for bilinear programming.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In case someone doesn't end up writing an algorithm here: The simplex method essentially searches for the optimum by moving from one adjacent vertex of the polyhedron to another.  I think if you study some implementations of its pivot operation you will see how to do this.

Comment: @muaddib I tried, but had the following question. For a nondegenerate vertex, it has $n$ adjacent vertices. In the simplex textbooks, they say that to get an adjacent vertex, we just need to switch one basic variable with one nonbasic variable. However, there are $m$ basic variables and $n-m$ nonbasic variables. Therefore, the total number of such switches is $m(n-m)$. But I know, there are only $n$ adjacent vertices. So am I missing something?

Comment: This looks like a good new question to ask.